# CentOS 7 Static Routing

Tags: centos, routing

I want to create a static route through a CentOS 7 Server (so that a print server can access a printer).
CentOS 7 Server has two interfaces: em1 (10.0.0.5/24 faces the print server) and em2 (10.0.0.6/24 faces the printer). I have not defined a gateway for em2.
Print Server has IP address 10.0.0.60/24. Printer has IP address 10.0.0.4/24. The printer's gateway is 10.0.0.6.
Services iptables and firewalld are disabled. The intent is to enable and use one of them as a firewall once we figure out routing.
[image]
Steps I have taken:

- Added the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
- Issued the command:
  **ip route add 10.0.0.4 dev em2**
  This allowed me to ping the printer from within the server but not from outside
  If this route is not set, I cannot ping the printer from the CentOS server.
- Attempted adding the command
  **ip route add 10.0.0.254 dev em1**
  To set a route from the em2 to the default gateway. This had no positive effect.
- Removed both of the previous commands using **ip route del**
- Created file /etc/sysconf/network-scripts/route-em2 with the following line:
  **10.0.0.4 dev em2**
  Restarted network using **systemctl restart network**
  Still unable to ping from outside, but able to ping the printer from the CentOS 7 printer but not from the network.
- Enabled iptables and ran the following commands to enable ping through the server:
  **iptables --flush**
  **iptables -A FORWARD -i em1 -o em2 -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT**
  **iptables -A FORWARD -i em2 -o em1 -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT**
  Running these iptables commands did not affect my ability to ping the printer from the print server, but I am still able to ping the printer from the CentOS server.
- Using the nm-connection-gui, I added the ip address of the printer as an additional ip address on em1. Doing this allows me to ping 10.0.0.4 (printer IP). However, this merely sets up the server as the destination for that IP, and does not allow me to connect to the printer.

Thus far I cannot ping the system from an outside server.
A couple of other things:
- em2 does not have a default gateway specified.
- In the GUI connection manager, the routes shown in the route-em2 file are shown under "Routes" - I did not add them.
- In the GUI connection manager, "Use this connection only for resources on its network" is checked. If I uncheck it, the apply button does not highlight.
- In the GUI connection manager, there are no routes specified for em1. The "Automatic" switch is "ON" for routes on both em1 and em2.

It seems like I have routing set up properly on the local server. I need to figure out how to get other servers to connect to the printer via my CentOS 7 server.

[image]

ifcfg-em1 file contents
    TYPE=Ethernet
    PROXY_METHOD=none
    BROWSER_ONLY=no
    BOOTPROTO=none
    DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    IPV6INIT=yes
    IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
    IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
    NAME=em1
    UUID=98f63db9-9676-4b85-acce-8292ceee303b
    DEVICE=em1
    ONBOOT=yes
    IPADDR=10.0.0.5
    PREFIX=24
    GATEWAY=10.0.0.254
    DNS1=10.0.0.3
    DNS2=10.0.0.6
    DOMAIN=REDACTED-FROM-THIS-POST
    IPV6_PRIVACY=no

ifcfg-em2 file contents
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=em2
UUID=f43a309a-a80f-4200-a252-02cf2648574a
DEVICE=em2
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=50:9A:4C:6C:79:0B
IPADDR=10.0.0.6
PREFIX=24
IPV6_PRIVACY=no

Comment: All of the IP addresses you give are 10.0.0.x/24.  That means as far as the computers are concerned, all of them are on the same subnet, 10.0.0.  What you are describing implies to me that you want 2 different subnets.  Try setting up one side to be something like 10.0.1.x/24.  Leave the other side as 10.0.0.x/24.

Comment: Lewis M: I have been working on this to replace a deprecated server. The previous server was set up similar to this.

Comment: Also, this is to eventually be a firewall. I believe that the desire is for the printer ip addresses to be the same subnet as the print server.

Comment: Based on your comments, I get the feeling your diagram is not totally accurate.  I suspect that there are 2 switches at least involved, yes?  If so, could you update your diagram to show that?  What you have currently could be interpreted as all being on the same subnet connected to the same set of switches that can talk to each other.  If each side has switches that cannot talk to each other, showing that in the diagram clarifies that the CentOS box is your router/firewall.

Comment: You are correct - I have edited the drawing. There may actually be more than one switch between the print server and the CentOS 7 server, as they are in different buildings. The CentOS7 server - printer side is accurate now.

Comment: The diagram has 2 em1.

Comment: Based on what you had in the diagram, and what you have in your question, you want a static route on the print server at 10.0.0.60 so that when it tries to connect to the printer at 10.0.0.4, it uses the CentOS server.  So, your static route on the print server needs to route 10.0.0.4 packets to the 10.0.0.5 IP address on the CentOS server.  The CentOS server will then forward them to the other NIC, which will then deliver them to the printer.

Comment: Thanks Lewis M - I will try adding the routing table onto the print server, which is a Windows server. I will update this post if that works. Also, I updated the diagram.

Comment: First attempt with adding the routing table still left me unable to ping.

Comment: The original configuration (CentOS 5) had everything the same EXCEPT that the em2 interface was configured with 192.168.130.3. Then there were commands in rc.local to delete the route, as in ip route del 192.168.130.0/24 dev em2. When it was configured this way the printers were still configured as they are, except that they used 10.0.0.254 as the default gateway. I tried all this and didn't get it to connect at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is not routing, it is the creation of a **bridged firewall**. The problem I was having with routing was that the systems on both sides of the firewall are from the same subnet. Most literature about firewalls (online and in print) assumes that the firewall is a router or is adjacent to one, and that machines on different sides are on different subnets. When the machines are on the same subnet, a **network bridge** is the easiest solution.

I was able to implement a solution using a very simple bridge interface configuration as is described in the Red Hat Administration documents [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge). Once this bridge was in place, I utilized [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.org/) software to mange firewall rules. While Shorewall was my choice, a knowledgeable administrator would be able to do the same using iptables services or firewalld. Shorewall provides a helpful instructional page specific to building a bridged firewall [here](http://www.shorewall.org/bridge-Shorewall-perl.html), and this was instrumental in my choice.

I would like to offer my appreciation to the other users who supplied thought-provoking comments to this question.